# How to get an inscription from a div?

Tags: javascript, html, get, user-experience

Hi I wanted to get my inscription "something" and show it on the screen every 2 seconds.
Something doesn't work. Thanks for all help :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body> 

<div id = "word">something</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

var myVar = document.getElementById("word");

setInterval(function func1(){
document.write(myVar)
},2000);

func1();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

```
var myVar = document.getElementById("word").innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to run the function manually, setInterval will execute it every 2 seconds.

```js
setInterval(() => {
  const word = document.getElementById('word');
  const output = document.getElementById('output');
  output.innerHTML = word.innerHTML;
}, 2000);
```

```html
<div id="word">Something</div>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: @unknown2549 maybe you also need to clear the result? If so, tell me what do you need and I'll edit my answer

Answer (score 1):

1. add innerHTML to extract data from div.
2. You don't need to name the recurring function.

```js
var myVar =  document.getElementById("word").innerHTML;
setInterval(function(){
document.write(myVar);
// alert(myvar);
},2000);
```

```html
<div id="word">test</div>
```